# how do i edit my CSS to show following things please

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm experimenting with bootstrap and come up with below menu bar and slider:

http://tumolo.co.uk/fcslfn/

The rest of the site is built from this template:
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/

I would like to know how to:

1. the FB logo and Twitter logo has a black horizontal line between them - how can i make that disappear?
2. how do i make the slider responsive?
3. How do I neaten up the menu bar, so that the football badge is centred and the menu items on either side, are proportionally separated?

Comment: unfortunately the questions answered here are more of 'Why' than 'HOW'.

Comment: huh? I'm experimenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Part One Update the http://tumolo.co.uk/fcslfn/css/general.css file

```
#top-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: -1px !important;
    margin-left: -1px !important;
}
```

For Two You can Change the Carousel to Responsive one [Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Full-Width-Responsive-Carousel-with-jQuery-Bootstrap/) and [Source](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Full-Width-Responsive-Carousel-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html)

For the Third Change the Position of the Logo in small device view you can do this by using the [responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) available in bootstrap